# How to emulate an i2c device on QEMU x86?

Tags: qemu, i2c

I am work on QEMU 1.5/1.6, but haven't seen any docs for adding an device on i2c bus.
Can any one help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, nobody interested in this issue.
I post my own solution. 
Cause QEMU does not support I2C bus level data transfer, it has delay when transfer multi-touch data from QEMU to guest Linux.
So we create a shared memory on guest Linux kernel driver, and QEMU transfers the data directly through the shared memory, and it has a good speed.

Comment: I am also trying to emulate an SMBus\I2C device on QEMU , since I could not find a proper documentation about this. Can you please let me know how were you able to emulate an SMbus\I2C device on QEMU. Your answer could be of great help to me.