# I2C IOCTL Write Failure

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux, i2c, petalinux

Hey I am trying to write a user space application to move some data to an I2C for an embedded system running PetaLinux, an operating system for embedded Linux, although I do not think that is what is affecting the issue. I am getting a Connection timeout and a segmentation fault.

The function has macros that direct it to write to the first I2C bus. I specify the data that I want to write in main and pass it to i2c_write, which then passes it to i2c_ioctl_write.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <linux/i2c.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#define I2C_ADAPTER "/dev/i2c-0"
#define I2C_DEVICE  0x00
#define REG_ADDR 0x00


int i2c_ioctl_write (int fd, uint8_t dev, uint8_t regaddr, uint16_t *data)
{
    printf("i2c_ioctl_write\n");
    int i, j = 0;
    int ret;
    uint8_t *buf;

    buf = malloc(1 + 2 * (sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0])));
    if (buf == NULL) {
        return -ENOMEM;
    }
    printf("\tBuffer Allocation Successful...\n");

    buf[j ++] = regaddr;
    for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0])); i ++) {
        buf[j ++] = (data[i] & 0xff00) >> 8;
        buf[j ++] = data[i] & 0xff;
    }
    printf("\tBuffer Setup Successful...\n");

    struct i2c_msg messages[] = {
        {
            .addr = dev,
            .buf = buf,
            .len = sizeof(buf) / sizeof(buf[0]),
        },
    };
    printf("\tSetup I2C Messages...\n");

    struct i2c_rdwr_ioctl_data payload = {
        .msgs = messages,
        .nmsgs = sizeof(messages) / sizeof(messages[0]),
    };
    printf("\tSetup I2C IOCTL Payload...\n");


    ret = ioctl(fd, I2C_RDWR, &payload);
    printf("\tWrote with IOCTL...\n");
    if (ret < 0) {
        ret = -errno;
    }

    free (buf);
    return ret;
}

int i2c_ioctl_smbus_write (int fd, uint8_t dev, uint8_t regaddr, uint16_t *data)
{
    printf("i2c_ioctl_smbus_write\n");
    int i, j = 0;
    int ret;
    uint8_t *buf;

    buf = malloc(2 * (sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0])));
    if (buf == NULL) {
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0])); i ++) {
        buf[j ++] = (data[i] & 0xff00) >> 8;
        buf[j ++] = data[i] & 0xff;
    }

    struct i2c_smbus_ioctl_data payload = {
        .read_write = I2C_SMBUS_WRITE,
        .size = I2C_SMBUS_WORD_DATA,
        .command = regaddr,
        .data = (void *) buf,
    };

    ret = ioctl (fd, I2C_SLAVE_FORCE, dev);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        ret = -errno;
        goto exit;
    }

    ret = ioctl (fd, I2C_SMBUS, &payload);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        ret = -errno;
        goto exit;
    }

exit:
    free(buf);
    return ret;
}

int i2c_write (int fd, uint8_t dev, uint8_t regaddr, uint16_t *data)
{
    printf("i2x_write\n");
    uint64_t funcs;

    if (ioctl(fd, I2C_FUNCS, &funcs) < 0) {
        return -errno;
    }

    if (funcs & I2C_FUNC_I2C) {
        return i2c_ioctl_write (fd, dev, regaddr, data);
    } else if (funcs & I2C_FUNC_SMBUS_WORD_DATA) {
        return i2c_ioctl_smbus_write (fd, dev, regaddr, data);
    } else {
        return -ENOSYS;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("main\n");
    uint8_t regaddr;
    int fd;
    int ret = 0;

    uint16_t data[] = {1, 2, 4};

    fd = open(I2C_ADAPTER, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);
    ret = i2c_write(fd, I2C_DEVICE, REG_ADDR, data);
    close(fd);

    if (ret) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s.\n", strerror(-ret));
    }

    free(data);

    return ret;
}
```

When I run the program on QEMU I get the following output:

> main
>   i2x_write
>   i2c_ioctl_write
>   Buffer Allocation Successful...
>   Buffer Setup Successful...
>   Setup I2C Messages
>   Setup I2C IOCTL Payload
>   cdns-i2c e0004000.i2c: timeout waiting on completion
>    Wrote with IOCTL
>   Connection timed out.
>   Segmentation fault

I assume it is failing on the line

```
ret = ioctl(fd, I2C_RDWR, &payload);
```

but I am not sure why. Was the payload constructed improperly?

Update: Here is the current code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdint.h>
 #include <inttypes.h>

 #include <errno.h>
 #include <string.h>

 #include <sys/stat.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <unistd.h>

 #include <linux/i2c.h>
 #include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
 #include <sys/ioctl.h>

 #define I2C_ADAPTER "/dev/i2c-0"
 #define I2C_DEVICE  0x00

 int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    int ret = 0;


    fd = open(I2C_ADAPTER, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);

    uint64_t funcs;

    int addr = 0X00;

    if (ioctl(fd, I2C_SLAVE, addr) < 0) {
        /* ERROR HANDLING; you can check errno to see what went wrong */
            printf("Cannot setup as slave");
            exit(1);
         }

    if (ioctl(fd, I2C_FUNCS, &funcs) < 0) {
        printf("ioctl failed");
        return -errno;
    }

    printf("funcs & I2C_FUNC_I2C:   %llu\n", funcs & I2C_FUNC_I2C);
    printf("funcs & I2C_FUNC_SMBUS_WORD_DATA:   %llu\n", funcs & I2C_FUNC_SMBUS_WORD_DATA);

    __u8 reg = 0x10;
    __s32 res;

    if (funcs & I2C_FUNC_I2C) {
        char buf[10];
        printf("Attempting to write to I2C bus via I2C protocol...\n");
        buf[0] = reg;
        buf[1] = 0x43;
        buf[2] = 0x65;
        int bytes_written = write(fd, buf, 3);
        if(bytes_written != 3) {
            printf("Wrote %d bytes", bytes_written);
            printf("\tFailed to write to I2C Bus\n");
            close(fd);
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            printf("\tSuccesful write to I2C Bus\n");
        }

        char buf2[10];
        printf("Attempting to read from I2C bus via I2C protocol...\n");
        if(read(fd, buf2, 1) != 1) {
            printf("\tFailed to do I2C read from Bus\n");
            close(fd);
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            printf("\tRead successful. Comparing read results from original write buffer...");
            printf("\t\tWritten value: %c", buf[0]);
            printf("\t\tRead value: %c", buf2[0]);
        }


        return 0;


    } else if (funcs & I2C_FUNC_SMBUS_WORD_DATA) {
        printf("Attempting to write to I2C bus via SMBus protocol...\n");
        //res = i2c_smbus_write_word_data(fd, REG_ADDR, 0x6543);
        res = 1;
        if(res < 0) {
            printf("\tFailed to write to I2C Bus\n");
            close(fd);
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            printf("\tSuccesful write to I2C Bus\n");
        }

        //res = i2c_smbus_read_word_data(fd, REG_ADDR);
        if(res < 0) {
            printf("\tFailed to read from I2C Bus\n");
            close(fd);
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            printf("\tRead successful. Comparing read results from original write buffer...");
            printf("\t\tWritten value: %c", 0x6543);
            printf("\t\tRead value: %c", res);
        }
    } else {
        printf("Cannot write to I2C");
        return -ENOSYS;
    }

    close(fd);

    if (ret) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s.\n", strerror(-ret));
    }

    return ret;
}
```

I was able to get rid of the seg fault by removing free(), so thanks there. I have pinpointed the exact issue of the timeout which occurs in the Cadence I2C Driver here:

https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx/blob/3f3c7b60919d56119a68813998d3005bca501a40/drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-cadence.c#L825

which is still occurring.

As mentioned, there is probably some issue with the way I am writing to slave causing the slave to not send ACK, resulting in a timeout. I am not sure which registers I will need to write what to. I have a feeling the I2C_DEVICE macro and addr and reg variables will need to be changed.

Comment: The obvious reason of the segfault is - `free(data)` at the end of main().

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconvertion -std=gnu11 )  To get you started, when the parameters from `main()` are not used, then use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: regarding: `for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0])); i ++) {`  the variable 'data' is just a pointer, not the actual array so `sizeof(data)` will return the size of a pointer, not the size of the array and `sizeof(data[0]) will return 2,   Similarity this statement: `buf = malloc(2 * (sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0])));` becomes 4/2*2  I.E. 4  so the code will be accessing beyond the end of the allocated memory.  This is undefined behavior and (as you have seen) can result in a seg fault event

Comment: the use of `goto()` is a sure sign that the code logic needs re-evaluated.

Comment: `sizeof` returns a type of `size_t` (which is unsigned) however, in this statement: `for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0])); i ++)` that `size_t` is being compared to an `int` (variable 'i'),  Such comparisons between signed and unsigned variables is fraught with problems  Suggest keeping variable scope limited as much as possible to use: `for ( size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0])); i ++)`

Comment: Can you please mention output of the modified code.

Answer (score 1):

> cdns-i2c e0004000.i2c: timeout waiting on completion

It seems that i2c driver (cdns-i2s) doesnt recieves the acknowledgment from the slave. It may occur as you are using I2C-slave address as 0x00 which is a [general call address](https://www.i2c-bus.org/addressing/general-call-address/). While using general call address the second byte that is sent has a special purpose which is mentioned in the [i2c-specification](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10204.pdf) (section 3.1.13).

If you use general call address you need to follow the specification or else Try using the exact i2c slave address instead of general call address(0x00).

Comment: when you say exact address, you mean look at the Xilinx Zynq reference manual to find the physical address of the i2c controller and write to that?

Comment: @JohnFrye No, You must be sending data over I2C to some slave device connected to your Xilinx Znyc I2C controller. So, I am saying you to refer datasheet of the peripheral that is connected to your I2C which is acting as slave.

Comment: From the datasheet of the slave device, you will get the slave address. just replace I2C_DEVICE with that address

Comment: I am running on QEMU, so I am not sure how to tell which peripheral is connected to the I2C to look it up on the datasheet.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501660/how-to-emulate-an-i2c-device-on-qemu-x86. Check if you can create and use virtual I2C slave on QEMU.

Comment: It looks like that link you posted might be the underlying problem. QEMU doesn't simulate I2C devices it lists under /dev . I am not sure what that answer means by "a shared memory on guest Linux kernel driver, and QEMU transfers the data directly through the shared memory"