# Emulate I2C on QEMU Aarch64

Tags: embedded-linux, qemu, xilinx, i2c

I have read this post [How to emulate an i2c device on QEMU x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501660/how-to-emulate-an-i2c-device-on-qemu-x86) about a solution for configuring an I2C device for QEMU emulating x86_64.

I am trying to do the same thing for ARM. Currently I have a simple I2C user space program that is timing out because although QEMU lists an I2C device in /dev it has no actual method of simulating the device and returning ACK. I was curious if someone could provide more detail on how I might implement the solution from that post because I am not very experienced in that area and the answer is pretty sparse in detail.

I am wondering how peripheral devices, other than USB, like ones using CAN and SPI are emulated when using QEMU.

Answer (score 2):

Devices are supported on a device-by-device basis. QEMU emulation of Zynq 7000 can emulate certain EEPROM and flash devices and read and write to them over the I2C bus. Device support is listed here. Xilinx QEMU peripheral device support: http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/QEMU+-+Zynq-7000

I assume that support for other machine types is also on a by device basis, and hopefully it is as well documented as Xilinx's QEMU machines' peripheral support.

The wiki provided has other pages which provide examples of adding peripheral devices to the device tree. When you specify the device tree at QEMU invocation, QEMU will read the device tree and will begin emulating devices for which it has support.